# Adding a comment to an event during registration

Tags: civievent, profile, registration

Created an event with a profile for registration information.  One of the fields added to the profile was the Note field, associated with a contact.  However, when the confirmation e-mail was sent, the e-mail included the last note connected to the contact, yet the current note was created in the primary contact record without any link to event registration.  It also does not show up when you view the registration.  Additionally, the note did not attach to the secondary contact that was registered in the same registration.

Said a different way.  Contact1 created an event registration and included a note in the contact note field that was part of the profile.  Rather than attaching that note to the confirmation e-mail, the note that was attached was the newest note linked to each Contact.  For Contact1, that was an e-mail from a month ago.  For Contact2, whom Contact1 was registering, it was an e-mail from a year ago.  Afterwards, the system then created the note from the registration form, attaching it to Contact1's contact record, but did not attach the note to Contact2 or the registration.

What's the proper way to create a comment field on an event registration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could setup a custom field for *participants* of the event (not contacts, nor the event, but the registration itself; Civi differentiates between contacts and participants; the registration entity is called 'Participants').

When creating the Custom Field Set, the "Used For" field would be for `Participants` (again, this is different from Contact).  Then when you add the field to the Profile you are going to use, the first dropdown for Field Name would be Participants; the second dropdown would be the custom field you just created.

Done this way, the Notes custom field you created only appears in the registration information (if you View the registration under a contact's Event tab), not in the Contact's Notes tab.

More details here: http://book.civicrm.org/user/events/setup/

Regarding the token for the confirmation email, because the custom field is for the registration/`participant` entity and not the `contact` entity, I think you will have to [create a custom Token](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customized+%28and+Custom%29+Tokens) to access that data in the email template.

Comment: Hrm ... Not exactly ideal, but a custom field could take care of it.  However, this comment field really should attach to the registration, not the participant or event.  Looking at the description, I'm reading it as attaching it to the event would be more for conveying info to participants. I'm thinking of it as an "Other" box, to get info from participants.  Am I missing the point?

Comment: Ah, I think understand what you're getting at.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: You could also set up a custom field for the contact and use that field in your profile. Rather then the notes

Comment: @JaapJansma:  That's a hack that is going to end up biting you in the rear later.  By doing so, you either have to create a custom field for every event, or you are changing the field for every registration.  This is most problematic when you have concurrent/overlapping event registrations as you can't have separate notes for each registration.

Comment: We got close, but if they weren't logged in yet, then the field didn't show up and the whole registration exploded.  I haven't had a chance to go back and figure out which piece was broken.

Comment: Hmmm... In your CMS permissions do anonymous users have access to custom fields?

Comment: Yes, CiviCRM: access all custom data, is checked all the way across.