# Add Questions to Event Registration

Tags: registration, online-registration

Our event registration needs to have two "yes or no" questions added for the attendee to answer when registering.  Is that possible?  Thanks

Comment: This seems similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8805/adding-a-comment-to-an-event-during-registration?rq=1.  You can create custom fields as described there. Also see the documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/custom-data-for-events/

Comment: Thank you!  The answer was found in https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/custom-data-for-events/